# django framework: get value from django.db.models.fields.IntegerField

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, pymysql

How can I get value from class django.db.models.fields.IntegerField?
I want get 1 from admin field.
This is python code: model class and function view

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import connection
import pymysql
    
# Create your models here.

class Users(models.Model):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.firstname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        self.lastname=models.CharField(max_length=100) 
        self.username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        self.password=models.CharField(max_length=255)
        self.admin=models.IntegerField()
        self.createdAt=models.DateTimeField(db_column="created_at")

    def getAdmin(self):
        return self.admin

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
```

A view function when I run `user = Users.objects.get(id=userId)`

```
def home(request):    
    #controllo se sei loggato
    if request.session.has_key('loggedin'):
        if request.session['loggedin'] != True:
            return redirect("login")
    else:
        return redirect("login")
    
    #l'utente è loggato recupero le informazioni
    userId = int(request.session['id'])
    user = Users.objects.get(id=userId) 
    print(type(user))
    print(type(user.getAdmin()))
    tmplVar = {}
    tmplVar["admin"] = user.admin
    return render(request, 'pygiustizia/home.html',{'tmplVar': tmplVar})
```

Comment: The code you have seems correct. Both `user.admin` and `user.getAdmin()` as you have written it should return the integer stored in the `admin` column in the row for that user. To get the help you need, please be sure to include any errors or unexpected behavior you're seeing and include what the behavior you expect should be.

Comment: Ok, it should print "1" instead it print the type <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField>

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior... Maybe there is some other error in your code not shown here? Maybe you're accidentally replacing `user` with the class instance of an instance?

Comment: Read my answer. The problem is super method.

Comment: Ah, yeah. You must define fields as _class_ attributes, not attributes on the instance! Generally speaking, you rarely if ever have to write `__init__` method for a model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume, you want the value of admin. From my understanding what you can do is you can use filter method on you object inside your `Users` model. As you have intialized the model fields inside the `__init__` method, that I am sure is not a good practice, but based on your requirement here you can do:

```
from django.db import models
    
# Create your models here.

class Users(models.Model):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.firstname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        self.lastname=models.CharField(max_length=100) 
        self.username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        self.password=models.CharField(max_length=255)
        self.admin=models.IntegerField()
        self.createdAt=models.DateTimeField(db_column="created_at")

    def getAdmin(self):
        return self.objects.get(admin=self.admin)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
```

Then you can replace your line `user = Users.objects.get(id=userId)`
with
`user = User(userId)`

I hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: it print <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField> instead 1. I don't understand, the code is right.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing the type not the value

```
print(type(user))
print(type(user.getAdmin()))
```

if you try something like:

```
print(user)
print(user.admin)
```

you should get something on the note of:

```
>> <object>
>> 1
```

unless you redefine `__repr__` or `__str__`

Comment: You are right. I change in print("quello",user.getAdmin()) but anyway print "quello <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField>"